# Admin user can't login

Tags: craft3

I need help getting an admin user logged in. The password was reset and doesn't work. After resetting the admin user password using forgot password, I get prompted with Invalid username or password. I can verify the password is updating in the DB when I change it via forgot password. Server is PHP 7.3.11 and Craft is 3.5.5. I'm not getting any console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a place for questions rather than bug reports, and it is unclear which this is.

I suggest you start troubleshooting by resetting the password via the `users/set-password` console command, for example:

```shell
php craft users/set-password my-username --password 1234567890
```

If that doesn't work, for whatever reason, then perhaps the user record has somehow been corrupted, in which case it may be better to simply create a new admin user.

```shell
php craft users/create --admin
```

Here are the docs for the `users` commands, for reference:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#users